# Django differentiate between incorrect login information and inactive user on login

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Currently I added in my site a method for email confirmation when registering. What I saw though, is that when the user is registered, but didn't click in the confirmation link yet and tries to login, I can't differentiate between wrong user/password and not confirmed user.

This is my login function:

```
def loginUser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("decks:index")
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("myApp:portal")
            elif user is not None:
                messages.error(request, "Email is not confirmed.")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, "myApp/login.html", context = {'login_form': form})
```

The problem is that when running `form.is_valid()` the `authenticate` function from `/home/nowork/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth` `ModelBackend` is executed:

```
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    if username is None or password is None:
        return
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
        # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
        UserModel().set_password(password)
    else:
        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
```

So the `form.is_valid()` will never be true when the `is_active` flag is `False`. So I have no way of telling if the combination of user+password is incorrect or the user is not confirmed yet.

I'm not sure what's the correct way of doing this, I thought to do something like:

```
User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
```

Can users exploit this somehow? Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Using python3 and Django 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own `CustomLoginBackend` as

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CustomLoginBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, username, password):
        User = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = User.objects.using(db_name).get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

Then in your `views.py`

```
def loginUser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("decks:index")
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active == True:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect("myApp:portal")
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Email is not confirmed.")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, "myApp/login.html", context = {'login_form': form})
```

And at last don't forgot to add `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your `settings.py` as

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path_to_your.CustomLoginBackend ',]
```

Comment: I guess this is the best approach! In that case, I need to omit `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` from `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` too, right?

Comment: By default `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is set to `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` and if there are multiple django tries authenticating all of its authentication backends and in order i.e. if first fails then django tries second and so on. If you have not set multiple backends then you can set this `CustomLoginBackend` only and can remove the `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`. But if there are multiple then order must be important.

Comment: Yes, got another but it should be fine. Also, what about the `request.user.is_authenticated` now? Will it return `True` even if the user is not active? Or this flag is only `True` after calling the `login` function?

Comment: If your user is inactive i.e. `is_active=False`  then `request.user.is_authenticated` will return false since user is not logged in yet. Yes you are right the flag will return true only after `login` function.